# Handler did not return a Snowpark DataFrame. Return a DataFrame from the handler or change the return type for the Python worksheet

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I have been trying to create a UDTF from which we can extract the matching values from the string and create 2 different columns in the table. Our idea is to input a string or an object column in the function and function will give matching term and matching value. So matching term is the highest valued word amongst given identifiers (which are already hard-coded in function).

I am using fuzzywuzzy package for finding matching values.

Below is code of this function and but I am not able to crack the error (which I have mentioned above)

`

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col, udtf
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process
from snowflake.snowpark.types import IntegerType, StringType, StructType, StructField
from typing import Iterable, Tuple

def main(session: snowpark.Session):
    @udtf(name="string_match_fn", session=session, input_types = [StringType()], output_schema=StructType([StructField("match_term", StringType()), StructField("match_value",IntegerType())]), stage_location="@fuzz_stg", replace=True)
    class Match_str:
        def __init__(self):
            self._match_term = []
            self._match_value = []

        def process(self, column_name: str):
            
            identifiers = ["RM-PORT_AGT", "RM-B2C_AGT", "JRNLS-AGT", "ATP"]
            for i in column_name:
                ratio = process.extract(i, identifiers, limit=1, scorer=fuzz.partial_ratio)
                self._match_term.append(ratio[0][0])
                self._match_value.append(ratio[0][1])
            self._match_term = pd.Series(self._match_term)
            self._match_value = pd.Series(self._match_value)

        def end_partition(self) -> Iterable[Tuple[str, int]]:
            yield (self._match_term, self._match_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are running your code in a Python Worksheet. If your function does not return a DataFrame type (which is default for the worksheet) then you should change it to String or Variant depending on what you want to return in the setting on the top panel. See the screenshot:

[image]